# Debugging GSstreamer in C#

Tags: c#, gstreamer

I'm trying to do a custom console app with GStreamer in C#. I stepped into the necessity to use the debugging options that are mentioned [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html?gi-language=javascript) but I couldn't find a way to use them. I've searched in the GStreamer dev blog and the github and nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set environment options permanently:

1. Open Run box, or press `Windows key+R`
2. type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`
3. In the `System Properties` window click on `Environment variables` button (bottom right)
4. In the `Environment Variables` window add variable name and value. For example in the `New User Variable` window put `GST_DEBUG` in the `Variable name` and `2,audio*:6` in the `Variable value` box.
5. You have to restart Visual studio if opened.

You can also add them programmatically for the current process

Add a line like this at the beginning of the program:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_DEBUG", "2,audio*:6")
```